# Evaluating predictions consistently

Tags: prediction

I am confused about how to assess predictions I make (specifically on [PredictionBook](http://predictionbook.com/), but I believe my confusion isn't specific to PredictionBook). I'm not sure if Cross Validated is the proper place for this; let me know if another venue is better suited.

Here are some example predictions to get at the thing I'm confused about:

> 1. Prediction "Event A will not happen in 2016"; confidence: 99%

Event A doesn't happen, so I judge this prediction "correct"

> 2. Prediction: "Event A will happen in 2016"; confidence: 1%

Event A doesn't happen. Because this is the converse of (1), I mark this prediction "correct" to be consistent. (This is the thing I'm getting stuck on – I'm marking a prediction "correct" even though the stated prediction didn't occur).

> 3. Prediction: "Event A will not happen in 2016"; confidence: 60%

Event A doesn't happen, so I judge this prediction "correct"

> 4. Prediction: "Event A will happen in 2016"; confidence: 40%

Event A doesn't happen. I judge this prediction "correct" to be consistent with (3).

(4) seems wrong, but I'm following the same procedure there as with (2). So, I'm confused – am I supposed to evaluate (2) as incorrect even though its inverse would be judged correct? i.e. does evaluation hinge on the phrasing of the prediction? Or maybe (1) and (2) are different in some way beyond their phrasing?

Answer (score 1):

You'd capture more of the information in your data if you'd assess the *extent* to which Prediction (on a scale from 0% to 100%) is associated with Event (yes or no).  Some tools for doing this are Somers' D or Concordance (equal to the area under a ROC curve) and even correlation (technically, point-biserial correlation, but garden-variety Pearson *r* will yield the same thing).